# How to create an email field that is not detected as a login field

Tags: html, forms, password-manager

So I have a question about how password managers register login and registration fields.
When I use an email field, proton pass says that there is no login available when I should give me my email
Any ideas?
Code:

```
<label>Please enter your email</label>
<input type="email" placeholder="example@example.com" name="email" id="email" minlength="5" maxlength="255" require>
```

[image: Proton Pass Saying no login]

EDIT:
whole form:

```
    <form method="POST">
                    <label>Please enter your email</label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="example@example.com" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" maxlength="255" required>
                    <label>Poll Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Poll Name" name="B0tPollName" id="B0tNewPollName" minlength="5" maxlength="64">
                    <label>Answers</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Answer 1" name="B0tPollAnswer1" id="B0tNewPollAnswer1" minlength="5" maxlength="32">
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Answer 2" name="B0tPollAnswer2" id="B0tNewPollAnswer2" minlength="5" maxlength="32">
                    <?php 
                    function B0tAddNewPollAnswer() {
                        if ($_SESSION["B0tAnswareCounter"] <= 8) {
                            $_SESSION["B0tAnswareCounter"]++; 
                        }
                        header("Location: ./");
                        exit();
                    };
    
                    for ($i = 3; $i <= $_SESSION["B0tAnswareCounter"]; $i++) {
                        echo "<br> \n" . '<input type="text" placeholder="Answer ' . $i . '" name="B0tPollAnswer' . $i . '" id="B0tNewPollAnswer' . $i . '" minlength="5" maxlength="32"> ';
                    }
    
                    if (isset($_POST['B0tNewPollAddAnswerBtn'])) {
                        // Call the PHP function
                        B0tAddNewPollAnswer();
                    }
                    ?>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Add Answer"  name="B0tNewPollAddAnswerBtn" id="B0tNewPollAddAnswerBtn">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B0tNewPollSubmitBtn" id="B0tNewPollSubmitBtn">
                </form>
```

Comment: But _do_ you have appropriate logins for your current address? This question is strictly only about Proton Pass, so you should contact them if there is any issues.

Comment: This is your answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonPass/comments/17ccc5w/autocompleteoff_request/